# How to remove duplicate entries by two keys in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

i have this collection

[image]

i would to remove duplicate data according to X and y when they are the same values so in this case (need to remove when  z=3 and z =4)

i use

```
db.collection.aggregate([{"$sort":{ "_id": 1 }},{"$group":{"_id":"$x","doc":{"$first":"$$ROOT"}}},{"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$doc"}},{"$out":"collection"}])
```

but it used with one key x

```
Json View

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d9e7b4ad433ce84a235e93"), 
    "x" : NumberInt(1), 
    "y" : NumberInt(1), 
    "z" : NumberInt(1)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d9e7d0ad433ce84a235e95"), 
    "x" : NumberInt(1), 
    "z" : NumberInt(2), 
    "y" : NumberInt(2)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d9e7d2ad433ce84a235e97"), 
    "z" : NumberInt(3), 
    "x" : NumberInt(2), 
    "y" : NumberInt(3)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d9e7d4ad433ce84a235e99"), 
    "z" : NumberInt(4), 
    "x" : NumberInt(2), 
    "y" : NumberInt(3)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d9e7d7ad433ce84a235e9b"), 
    "x" : NumberInt(3), 
    "y" : NumberInt(4), 
    "z" : NumberInt(5)
}
```

Comment: please show a sample json doc from mongo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple parameter grouping. Try this code it will help to remove duplicates with multiple key values

```html
db.collection.aggregate([{ "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": { "x": "$x", "y": "$y" },
    "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
  }
},
{ "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$doc" } },
{ "$out": "collection" }]);
```

Comment: Add 'allowDiskUse' => true, to fix memory issue